# Rotating a Model Matrix by a quaternion

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, rotation, glm-math

I am following different OpenGL tutorials, and got stuck at the rotation of my model matrix. While the rotation for my direction vector of my camera works, the rotation for my model matrices doesnt.
Calling the rotate function just makes the mesh flicker when renderes via opengl. Id be glad if you could point out, what mistake I am doing here. I already tried changing the order of the transformations, I wonder if theres something wrong with how I use quaternions though.
Here is the relevant code:

```
//Position, Orientation, Scale
glm::mat4 model;
glm::vec3 translation = {0,0,0};
glm::vec3 scale = { 1,1,1 };
glm::mat4 rotation;

void GModel::rotate(float angle, glm::vec3 axis) {

        angle = angle* 3.141592 / 180; //rad

        float sinHalfAngle = sin(angle / 2);
        float cosHalfAngle = cos(angle / 2);

        float rX = axis.x*sinHalfAngle;
        float rY = axis.y*sinHalfAngle;
        float rZ = axis.z*sinHalfAngle;
        float rW = cosHalfAngle;

        glm::quat rota(rX, rY, rZ, rW);

        rotation = glm::mat4_cast(rota);

        modelMatrix();

}

void GModel::modelMatrix() {

    model = glm::translate(model, translation);
    model = glm::scale(model, scale);
    model = rotation*model;

}
```

Comment: Yes, the axis is normalized. I do call modelMatrix() in rotate, because I only want to update the matrix, if the object was rotated.

Comment: Quick question, why are you not using `glm::rotate`?

Comment: because glm::rotate is only available for the rotation of a vector, not a matrix. Or is there a library for matrices as well?

Comment: I am not shure but I think in the constructor of the quaternion it's w first. glm::quat rota(rW,rX, rY, rZ); it should not have any consequence but I think you should do the scale before the translation

Comment: I think you are trying to animate the object, however your modelMatrix calculation is better if you start it with ` glm::translate(glm(1.0f), translation);` and increase translation or multiply it with time. Your current implementation will cause jumps as your object is being rotated around not its origin but its translated origin.